# Bison useless non-term

Tags: bison

σI am trying to create a simple bison example. I have defined the operation's values from my .l file but when i try to do a -v check for conflicts, the expr is in no way connected to the stmt, therefore the bison recognizes just the 2 first things i wrote, even though i have a "expr SEMICOLON" in the beginning of the stmt. I am also getting a reduce/reduce conflict in state 0. Any ideas?

```
program: state
    |;

state: expr SEMICOLON
  | BREAK SEMICOLON
  | CONTINUE SEMICOLON 
  |;

expr: expr "+" expr
| expr "-" expr
| expr "*" expr
| expr "/" expr
| expr "%" expr
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the cases for `expr` are recursive, so there's no way for `expr` to ever match any input. You need a base case (`NUM` and/or `ID` for example).

The reduce/reduce conflict is caused by the fact that both `program` and `stmt` have an empty case. So since `stmt` is also one of the cases for `program`, there are two possible paths to derive the empty string from `program` (`program -> stmt -> ""` and `program -> ""`). So you need to remove one of the empty cases.

Comment: I see, I fixed them both, thanks for the great help, I am stuck here 45 minutes now doing nothing but deleting things. I think I'll be back with more questions later today, but for now, thanks.